# PDF creation in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to develop an asp.net MVC application that will allow the user to create his/her pdf document. i googled many sites and found info to create a single pdf document. In my application whenever user clicks on create PDF link he should be allowed to create a new PDF document. How can I do so?

Comment: please tag the question appropriately to get answer and before you ask question show what you have tried. some little effort needed to get the good answers

Answer (score 0):

Okay what you basically trying to achieve here is convert html to pdf.

you have a `<div id="myPDFCanvas"></div>` and inside that canvas u have text, images blah blah blah all the stuff you need. Then you need to convert this div canvas into pdf.

WkHtmlToXSharp will solve your problem

for a demo check [this out](https://github.com/pruiz/WkHtmlToXSharp)

Comment: i want something like this http://www.pdfescape.com/open/?853E7EF4C6DA696008280BF5F07C52B2B92C2277BB5FF6D2

Comment: I want to create a blank PDF file and the user should be able to enter the text or image in that file.

Comment: as suggested by shekkhar iTextSharp is also a good option. Play with them and find out which one suits you the best.

Answer (score 0):

I dont what do you want,
if you want to create PDF you can use [this library](http://scrybersamples.codeplex.com/)

> Scryber PDF Generator is the open source library for quickly creating
>   dynamic PDF documents with style.This project holds the source for the
>   guides and examples

Answer (score 0):

For PDF :-

I think you should use `itextSharp`. You can go through this link 
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81118/ITextSharp-Helper-Class
You can download it (.dll) from here
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/